# How to prove this logical equivalence with laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

So I´ve been trying to prove this logical equivalence with laws, but since I just learned them I don't know how to prove this one. I guess I'd start with the conditional law, but after that, I don't know...

(P -> Q) -> (Q v R) <=> P v Q v R

Comment: have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

$\sim(P\rightarrow Q)\vee(Q \vee R)$

$\sim(\sim P\vee Q)\vee(Q \vee R)$

$(P \wedge \sim Q)\vee(Q \vee R)$

$((P \wedge \sim Q)\vee Q) \vee R)$

$((P \vee Q)\wedge (Q \vee \sim Q) \vee R)$

$((P \vee Q)\wedge (T) \vee R)$

$((P \vee Q)\vee R)$